# работа с массивом в function JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Если не сложно объясните на пальцах, почему `function` не принимает (и конвертирует) массив в `undefind`. Заранее благодарю.

```
let rundomCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
let firstArray = [];
let doubleValue = [];
for (i = 0; i < rundomCount; i++) {                
  firstArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  firstArray.push(firstArray[i]);
}
alert(firstArray);

function sortArray(firstArray) {
  alert(firstArray); 
}
sortArray();
```

Comment: А где вы вызываете функцию?

Comment: sorry! Уже правил

Comment: когда вы пишите `function NameFunction(param)` вы в скобках указываете, что туда будет передаваться какой-то параметр, название параметра как имя переменной, если снаружи указать `varName` и в переметрах указать `varName`, то внутри функции будет вызываться именно параметр, а не переменная извне, т.к. название параметра != название переменной. А вызвав `sortArray()` вы ничего не передаёте, по этому параметр `firstArray = undefined`. Чтобы сработало, нужно написать `function sortArray(arr) {alert(arr)}; sortArray(firstArray);`

Comment: function promptOrderedProducts() {
     let products = [];
     for (let index = 0; index < names.length; index++) {
     const name = names[index];
     const price = prices[index];

           products[index] = +prompt(`Укажите количество продуктов '${name}', цена ${price}`, 0);
           }
           return products;}

        function calculateTotalPrice(products) {
            let sum = 0;
            for (let index = 0; index < products.length; index++)...
код с которого брал пример. return product возвращает аргумент (если я правильно понял), поэтому работает?!

Comment: De.Minov спасибо за разъяснение :)